# Incompatible chromedriver and chrome versions except they are both 96

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium python with chromedriver and I got the usual error about incompatible chromedriver and chrome versions:

```
session not created
from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.110)
```

I went and downloaded chromedriver 96 but I keep getting that same error.
Here is my output when i check the chromedriver version :

```
> chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 96.0.4664.45 (76e4c1bb2ab4671b8beba3444e61c0f17584b2fc-refs/branch-heads/4664@{#947})
```

Here is how I initialize the driver in my code:

```
options = Options()
port = '8888'
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=' + port)
options.add_argument('headless')
try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
except:
...
```

**EDIT :** After updating Selenium to ver. 4.1.0, I now get a stacktrace with the same error :

```
session not created
from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.110)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00916903+2517251]
    Ordinal0 [0x008AF8E1+2095329]
    Ordinal0 [0x007B2848+1058888]
    Ordinal0 [0x007A376E+997230]
    Ordinal0 [0x007B3A60+1063520]
    Ordinal0 [0x007FBA7A+1358458]
    Ordinal0 [0x007FA71A+1353498]
    Ordinal0 [0x007F639B+1336219]
    Ordinal0 [0x007D27A7+1189799]
    Ordinal0 [0x007D3609+1193481]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00AA5904+1577972]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00B50B97+2279047]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x009A6D09+534521]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x009A5DB9+530601]
    Ordinal0 [0x008B4FF9+2117625]
    Ordinal0 [0x008B98A8+2136232]
    Ordinal0 [0x008B99E2+2136546]
    Ordinal0 [0x008C3541+2176321]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76ACFA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77A17A9E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77A17A6E+238]
```

Comment: you downloaded it, but did you add it to your path so that it's preferred over whatever you had before?

Comment: Yes, I always replace the old driver with the new in the folder specified in the path. The `chromedriver --version`  would not return version 96 if it wasn't the right file

Comment: what is the version of your selenium package?

Comment: 3.141.0 it would seem

Comment: did you just restart your application? xD I confirm I am using Selenium 3.141.0 with Chromedriver 96.0.4664.45 in our project, without issues.

Comment: I updated it to 4.1.0 and I get the same bug but with a stack trace now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was related to the fact that I launched the driver in headless mode and that it doesn't stop itself when the program stops, which caused the program to crash when being started again.

Solution: use `driver.quit()` at the end of the program